# Angular: How to tell from elementRef whether element has given class applied to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In my Angular app, I have a component that triggers an event when I click on it. I can get the `elementRef` from this event, but I want to test whether that element has a certain class applied to it. So my code looks like this:

```
<component1 [class.class1]="this.condition">
```

and

```
@HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
    let elementRef = this.elementRef;
    // I want to know if 'elementRef' has class 'class1' applied to it.
  }
```

I want to do something like `elementRef.class1`. Does anyone know how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get nativeElement (via elementRef’s nativeElement property) and then use standard classlist.contains approach:

```
elementRef.nativeElement.classList.contains(class);
```

Not entirely sure of your use case, but if you want to "control" which class is enabled for your component you can leverage ngClass and bind each class to a condition in your ts:

```
<component1 [ngClass]="{ 'class1': isCondition1, 'class2': isCondition2 }"></component1>
```

So if your isCondition1 property results in 'true' then component1 will have class1 added to it etc

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I posted another similar question if you have any insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473992/angular-how-to-get-li-rather-than-ul-from-click-event