# Angular: how to get <li> rather than <ul> from click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an Angular component that has a `<ul>` element contains `<li>` elements. I have the following code:

```
  @HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
    func();
  }
```

I want `func()` to be executed whenever I click anywhere on the screen *except* for on certain `<li>` elements that have a `disabled` class applied to them. What I was hoping is that `event.target` would return the `<li>` I clicked on, so that I could do something like

```
if (!event.target.disabled) {
    func()
}
```

The problem is that `event.target` returns the `<ul>` rather than the `<li>`. Here's my template:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <ng-container>
      <ng-template>
        <li>
        <li class="disabled">
        <li>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This template can't change, because it's part of someone else's code.

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: Can you share template of your component? Seeing that would help with answer

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I've updated my post.

Comment: oh ok i see that the problem is that the li element is inside of shadow dom?

Comment: I don't know much about the shadow dom :)

Comment: can you provide more details 

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmavi Which details would help?

Comment: is the li elemnt is generated dynamics of just statis you are going to add the class

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmavi The <li>s are static. See my edit the my original post where I provided the template

Comment: Can you reproduce it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hostlisteners-qcvjsk?

Comment: @FatemeFazli Thanks for that! Working on figuring out the difference between my scenario and the one you made there. I'll get back to you asap.

Comment: you can use `e.stopPropagation` this will prevent the event of bubbling

Comment: check my answer and it has a live demo 

Comment: @RNdev have you check any of the answer if it work for you ? and both answer has a live demo you can check

Answer (score 0):

can you try this approach:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfonyy

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(event): void {
    this.func(event.target)
  }

  func(element) {
    if (element.tagName == ‘LI’ && element.classList.contains('disabled')) {
      console.log("clicked disabled li")
    } else {
      console.log("clicked elsewhere")
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to check also if the element is li otherwise the func will not work on any element has disabled class 

Comment: agree, i think it also depends on the use case and might require even more checks:)

Comment: you are right still I ask about more detail about the question but we provide an answers base what the RNdev give , good job 

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is bind these disabled elemnt to mousedown event and call `event.stopPropagation()` method.

*template*

```
<li class="disabled" (mousedown)="handler($event)">click</li>
```

*component*

```
handler(e:MouseEvent){
      e.stopPropagation();   
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4szdnt)

**Update !!**

you can still do the samething by using directive like this and target nore event

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[prevEvents]'
})
export class PrevEventsDirective {

  @HostListener("mousedown", ["$event"]) 
  @HostListener("mouseup", ["$event"]) 
  @HostListener("click", ["$event"]) 
  public handler(e:MouseEvent) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

}
```

*template*

```html
<li class="disabled" prevEvents>click</li>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7pacbt)

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I've discovered that the difference between that and my app is that my HostListener keydown listener fires first, before handler() does. The HostListener closes the element, so handler() doesn't get a chance to fire. If I do 'setTimeOut()' on the HostListener with 300s, HostListener is delayed long enough that it works, but anything less than 200s, it fails. Any ideas on how to deal with that?

Comment: I am totally lost you don't tell about this in the question  what are the events that must be disabled

Comment: @RNdev I have update the answer with directive you can clarify your question with more details if this don't work for you so we can help 